# compare two dates in oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle

(I am using Oracle10g & Java(JDBC & Servlets))

Following is my query to compare *ETIME* with *sysdate*.

If *ETIME+7days*  is greater than *sysdate* then I want to select `Y` and if *ETIME+7days* is less than *sysdate* I want to select `N`.

```
select USER, 
       CASE WHEN to_date(ETIME+7, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') >= to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS')
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END THE_TIME
from TABLE_NAME
where THE_KEY='123456789'
```

[Note: In database value of `ETIME` for `THE_KEY` is `27/09/2013`]

Above query returns `N` today. Few days back it was returning `Y`. So I think I am doing comparison of two dates wrong way.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `to_date` function. Just compare the dates directly:

```
select USER, 
       CASE WHEN ETIME+7 >= sysdate
            THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END THE_TIME
from TABLE_NAME
where THE_KEY='123456789'
```

You can check why the original query went wrong. Run the following query and see how the `to_date` function convert the date.

```
select
  sysdate,
  to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS')
from dual
```

The first argument of `to_date` function should be date string like `'2013-SEP-27 05:29:26'`, not date itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
with t(user, etime, the_key) AS 
(
SELECT 1, SYSDATE - 1, '12345678' FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 2, SYSDATE - 8, '12345678' FROM dual
)
SELECT user, CASE WHEN ETIME + 7 >= sysdate
               THEN 'Y' 
             ELSE 'N' END THE_TIME
FROM t
where THE_KEY='12345678';
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong in particular other than the usage of `to_date()`. The only thing here can be that the ETIME has remained constant over the period of time, from your few days before till today.

Have a look at this example:-

**Few days back (on 23-Sep-2013)**

> ETIME = 19-Sep-2013
>
> ETIME + 7 = 26-Sep-2013
>
> Thus, your result was `Y` (Since sysdate was less than ETIME + 7)

**Today (on 27-Sep-2013)**

> ETIME = 19-Sep-2013 // same
>
> ETIME + 7 = 26-Sep-2013 // same
>
> Thus, your result was `N` (Since your sysdate is greater than ETIME + 7)